# Webform integration - how to I get a webform to create multiple records in a custom field set?

Tags: custom-fields, webform-civicrm, multi-record

Using Drupal 7.81 and Webform 4.x with CiviCRM Webform integration.

I have an application form that uses a custom field and this field is set to allow multiple records. The form is set to expose 6 records of data from the drop down (9 is the max from what I can see) and I use a fieldset for each one. 'Create/Edit' mode is set on each set.  I use a condidtional with 'more' to expose the next set if the applicant needs to add more data.

Contact1 is the applicant and a CiviCase is created for each application.

The webform submits fine, the contact and case are created. I can see each of the up to 6 rows of data for this field when I view the webform submission.  However, in CiviCRM only the first set of data is recorded in this custom field on the contact record, despite the webform appearing to have the correct fields displayed and exposed e.g. civicrm_1_contact_1_cg12_custom_123, civicrm_1_contact_2_cg12_custom_123, civicrm_1_contact_3_cg12_custom_123 etc.

What am i doing wrong in my form?!

Answer (score 3):

We recently did a fair bit of work on multiple multi-value fields and that issue is fixed in the latest and tested by a UK partner and his client:

https://github.com/colemanw/webform_civicrm

Fixed in 8.x-5.x - secured with a test and backported to 7.x-5.x - so it will be fixed when we push next releases to drupal.org

If you think that’s awesome  - you can always show your appreciation by sponsoring ongoing development of webform civicrm module -> https://webform-civicrm.io/form/sponsor-webform-civicrm-module

Answer (score 0):

I think its a bug, please see the link below:

https://www.drupal.org/project/webform_civicrm/issues/3199090